# How to create custom button in NetSuite?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I need in some help or guidance in the creation of custom button in NetSuite.

I want to create the custom button from the custom record type.
I have created the custom object where I have field to add the custom button name. Field to select the object example customer, Salesorder, etc.
Once the user submitted the custom record type the button need to created on the object choosen from the list.

The button need to show on record view.

I know using Suitescript user event how to create custom button.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are mixing some concepts.
A button can't be a custom record.
A button is used to make an action.
For example, you want a button on an invoice that will be used to send the invoice to a certain email address.
In that case, you will use a user event script that will create the button in the before load and you will attach a client script to it to perform the action while the user is on the page.

Answer (score 0):

The description is super confusing and i dont know what your purpose is .

3 ways to add buttons to your records.

1. Workflow - Add button
2. User Event addButton API using the form
3. Inject custom HTML button to record ( not recommended )